# List distinct values in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, distinct-values, r-faq

How can I list the distinct values in a vector where the values are replicative? I mean, similarly to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_code
FROM data
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Do you mean `unique`:

```
R> x = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4)
R> x
[1] 1 1 2 3 4 4 4
R> unique(x)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 17):

If the data is actually a `factor` then you can use the `levels()` function, e.g.

```
levels( data$product_code )
```

If it's not a factor, but it should be, you can convert it to factor first by using the `factor()` function, e.g.

```
levels( factor( data$product_code ) )
```

Another option, as mentioned above, is the `unique()` function:

```
unique( data$product_code )
```

The main difference between the two (when applied to a `factor`) is that `levels` will return a character vector in the order of levels, including any levels that are coded but do not occur. `unique` will return a `factor` in the order the values first appear, with any non-occurring levels omitted (though still included in `levels` of the returned factor).

Answer (score 8):

Try using the duplicated function in combination with the negation operator "!".

Example:

```
wdups <- rep(1:5,5)
wodups <- wdups[which(!duplicated(wdups))]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the sqldf package in R.

```
Z <- sqldf('SELECT DISTINCT tablename.columnname FROM tablename ')
```

Answer (score 0):

another way would be to use `dplyr` package:

```
x = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4)
dplyr::distinct(as.data.frame(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `R Language` (version 3.0+) You can apply filter to get unique out of a list-

`data.list <- data.list %>% unique`

or couple it with other operation as well

`data.list.rollnumbers <- data.list %>% pull(RollNumber) %>% unique`

`unique` doesn't require `dplyr`.

Comment: is there a function that replaces "pull" and "unique" altogether?

Comment: Currently I have not got such short notation in R. Python might be having it.

Answer (score 0):

this may work as well,

```
1) unlist(lapply(mtcars, function(x) length(unique(x))))
2) lapply(mtcars, function(x) unique(x))
```

outcomes,

1. ```
   mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
    25    3   27   22   22   29   30    2    2    3    6
   ```
2. ```
   $mpg
   [1] 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 13.3 27.3 26.0 15.8 19.7 15.0
   $cyl
   [1] 6 4 8
   $ and so on....
   ```

Comment: This won't give output as expected by OP!!