# Distinct values without using %>%

Tags: r

May Know what know is there in the below code. I am trying to extract distinct values of Species under iris but not getting . I am trying to code without %>%

```
iris[,c(distinct("Species"))]
```

Comment: Use this: `unique(iris$Species)`

Comment: Do you mean `distinct(iris, Species)`? The subsetting of the data frame on unique species does not make sense...

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/7755240/680068

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do this:

```
library(dplyr)    
distinct(iris, Species)
```

you do not need %>% to begin with, but if you mean that you don't want to use the dplyr package, maybe you can try what @sm925 suggested as a comment: `as.character(unique(iris$Species))`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a vector with all unique species:
`unique(iris$Species)`